# how to save dictionary data in core data using magical record

Tags: core-data, swift2, magicalrecord

I am new to *swift project* .I want to *save the data* in a dictionary in core data. Iam using magical records library. Please any help will appreciate .
[image]

Answer (score 0):

With Magical Record library importing values from dictionary to CoreData object is pretty simple. You should just do something like that:

```
MagicalRecord.saveWithBlock {
    (localContext) in
    let user = User.MR_importFromObject(dictionary, inContext: localContext)
}
```

This function will create new entity for you if it doesn't exist yet or update existing one and save this changes to CoreData persistent storage afterwards. But you should take care this entity has private key (so MagicalRecord will be able to perform entity search) and dictionary keys are mapped into entity's properties. To find more information about how to provide public key for CoreData entity and organize mapping with MagicalRecord follow [in this article](http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/).

Comment: can u please give me an example.this not working.i am getting an error.

Comment: cimgf is very good it helps me .but please suggest me some core level lyuna

Comment: What do you mean by core level? And which error are you getting?

Comment: I want to sync api data and save to my core data .Iam using magical record i don't have any experience on core data dam very new .so i need   let serialization : AFHTTPResponseSerializer =             manage.POST("http://userinfo API", parameters: ["userid":"\(userid)"],success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject?) -> Void inlet data = responseObject as! NSDatavar ResponseDict = NSDictionary()    //this ResponseDict i want save with my entities value hop u understand.Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is one more tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/56879/magicalrecord-tutorial-ios . Hope that helps you.